# Preloading of Javascript Files

Tags: javascript, html, preload

Working on a small engine to run my HTML5 test games, using it as a great way to get deeper into Javascript and have fun at the same time. Succeeding, btw.

However, I just found this cool little script called PreloadJS ( http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS ). Also using John Resig's classical inheritence class JS. Very cool, enjoying it. I am attempting to use PreloadJS to pull in all of my engine files...but I seem to be having an issue. Here's the code I'm using (keeping it simple on purpose):

```
var ScriptLoader = Class.extend({       // Want to add functionality to this to allow PHP or inline loading...perhaps later
  init: function() {

    this.fileList = [
        'Empty.js',
        './engine/Scene.js'
    ];

    this.preload;
  },

  loadProjectSource: function(directory) {
    if (this.preload != null) { this.preload.close(); }

    this.preload = new createjs.LoadQueue();
    this.preload.addEventListener("fileload", this.fileLoaded);
    this.preload.addEventListener("error", this.fileError);
    this.preload.setMaxConnections(5);

    this.loadAnother();

  },

  loadAnother: function() {
    var item = this.fileList.shift();
    if(this.fileList.length != 0) {
        this.preload.loadFile(item);
    }
  },

  fileLoaded: function(e) {
    debug('Loaded ' + e.item.src);
    this.loadAnother();
  },

  fileError: function(e) {
    debug('Error ' + e.item.src);
  }
}
```

From my engine instantiation, I'm calling ScriptLoader.loadProjectSource. It's doing nothing but throwing errors, and the documentation on error handling (and loading JS files in general...) is very sparse on the PreloadJS site. It focuses on preloading images (which, admittedly, looks great). Anyway, so yea, it's throwing errors. And it can't be the files, as I tried loading a completely blank JS file (as you can see). Still throwing an error on the Empty.js file.

Annoyed :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The PreloadJS script uses XHR where available with browser support. In order for this to function correctly with locally-hosted scripts, a local webserver must be running. Upon activating my local webserver and attempting the same operation, full success.